# Need help understanding the Basis Theorem and applying it in computation

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

The Basis theorem is stated as follows:
Let $V$ be a $p$-dimensional vector space where $p$ is equal to or greater than $1$. Any linearly independent set of exactly $P$ elements in $V$ is automatically a basis for $V$. Any set of exactly $P$ elements that spans $V$ is automatically a basis for $V$.

My question is what is $P$? Could $p$ be referring to the rank of a matrix? If I a given a set of two vectors and they are linearly independent would that make the set a basis, since it has two vectors and to be in $\mathbb R^2$ it must have at least $2$ vectors. So it could be in $\mathbb R^2$ but by showing it is consistent it would prove that it spans $\mathbb R^2$.

Now applying it to problems on my final:

Show that $$S=\{u_1,u_2\}$$
where 
$$
u_1=       \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        1\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
and $$
  u_2=
      \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        -1\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
is an orthoganl basis for $\mathbb R^2$.

I know that I can show it is orthogonal by showing the two vectors dot to 0. But How do I show that it is a basis using the above theorem?

Comment: Well, a set of orthogonal vectors is linearly independent. You have $2$ linearly independent vectors and the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $2$. Now refer to the theorem and you are done.

Comment: You should use the definition of linearly independence. That is for scalars $a_1 \& a_2$, if $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 = 0$ then $ a_1 = a_2 = 0$. If not you can use the fact that a set of orthogonal vectors are always linearly independent